# jquery hover range of td

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I'm new here, can't find any similar answer to what I want; I've made progress and can't go further. Below is my snipped, it change color when I hover between 2nd to 2nd last TR. (first TR is title and last TR is footer). Between the hover-able range, how can I select it only include 2nd TD and 2nd last TD.

```
$('table#tblSchoolList tr:gt(0)').hover(function(){
    ////and not the last child (.next length = 0 means last)
    if ( $(this).next().length != 0 ){
        $(this).css("background", "red");  
    }
}, function(){
    $(this).css("background", "");
})
```

In short, table hover exclude first and last TR and TD.

TIA.

Comment: Do you mean only change the color for the 2nd and 2nd-last cells of each row when you hover the row?

Comment: The code above worked for me as you described the requirements (highlights all trs between the first and last) - see http://jsfiddle.net/cK8Q5/1/

Comment: Yes BoltClock. Ken Redler just improved the tr range select but doesn't solve my question. The number of cells are dynamic, concept is same as tr, just not first and last cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find) with the following selector to exclude the first and last `td`s of each `tr`:

```
$('table#tblSchoolList tr:gt(0)').hover(function() {
    if ($(this).next().length != 0) {
        $(this).find('td:not(:first-child, :last-child)').css("background", "red");  
    }
}, function() {
    $(this).find('td:not(:first-child, :last-child)').css("background", "");
});
```

The function will still trigger if the mouse is over the first and last `td`s, but they won't color.

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/DLVSc)

You can also use the selector with your `tr`s, obviating the need for the if statement:

```
$('table#tblSchoolList tr:not(:first-child, :last-child)').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('td:not(:first-child, :last-child)').css("background", "red");
}, function() {
    $(this).find('td:not(:first-child, :last-child)').css("background", "");
});
```

---

As a little goodie, I noticed I was able to convert all your jQuery code to **one CSS rule** (that works only on modern browsers):

```
table#tblSchoolList tr ~ tr:not(:last-child):hover td ~ td:not(:last-child) {
    background: red;
}
```

Of course, you can always keep your jQuery solution if you want compatibility with older browsers or can't figure out what the above CSS means :)

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/DLVSc/2)

Comment: Thanks for your info. Good to know CSS rules work that way too.

Answer (score 2):

You might try using [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/), like this:

```
$('table#tblSchoolList tr').slice(1,-1).hover( function(){
  $(this).css("background", "red");  
}, function(){
  $(this).css("background", "");
});
```

Using a negative number specifies an offset from the end of the list. So:

```
slice(
  1, // omit first row
  -1 // omit last row
)
```

Or more simply:

```
$('table#tblSchoolList tr').slice(1,-1).hover( function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

(assuming you have a `highlight` class to handle the color behavior).

---

**Edit:** Updated to ensure that first and last columns, as well as rows, are not highlighted (thanks @boltclock):

```
$('#foo tr').slice(1,-1).hover( function(){
  $(this).find('td').slice(1,-1).toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

Here's a very simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/Mgd8f/

Comment: So... what about the `td`s? Right now all you're doing is refactoring what OP already has.

Comment: Thanks Ken, your suggestion improves my existing select but does not solve what I want. i.e between tr.slice(), I want also "td.slice()", something like "$('table#tblSchoolList tr').slice(1,-1).('td').slice(1,-1)" is it impossible?

Comment: I used a selector, but I'll admit slicing is much simpler.